# trying to seed my DB on rails - needs interpolation - Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, interpolation, seed

So here is what I am trying to do:

---

```
big_arr.each do |el|

  complement_text = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original'

  Movie.create(title: el["title"], overview: el["overview"], poster_url: `#{complement_text}#{el["poster_path"]}`, rating: el["vote_average"])

end
```

---

This is what API gives me:

```
"poster_path":"/2CAL2433ZeIihfX1Hb2139CX0pW.jpg"
```

---

This is error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - **https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/2CAL2433ZeIihfX1Hb2139CX0pW.jpg**
```

---

I just wanted this data passed on the error to be the value of my poster_url key.

What I did to solve it was to seed just what API gives me and on the view I added the rest. However, I'd like the user to add other movies with any random image url.

Anyone could bright this beginner? Thanks! :)

Comment: It looks like the issue with how the URL is being used. It sounds like you want it used a string, but something is trying to use it as a URL and then finding that the file specified isn't accessible. Can you show some more code for where the value is being used?

Comment: Oh - Yeah; can you show the `Movie` model code?

Answer (score 1):

The backtick (`) is a special symbol on ruby that invokes the shell. Anything in those quotes gets run as a shell command and then the result returned to ruby.

For example try:

```
s = `pwd`
puts s
```

`s` will be the current working directory as a string, since that is the output of the `pwd` shell command.

The error you receive is from the shell run through ruby since `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/2CAL2433ZeIihfX1Hb2139CX0pW.jpg` is not a valid shell command.

You probably didn't want to run the shell, if you just want string interpolation, use double quotes (").

```
poster_url: "#{complement_text}#{el['poster_path']}"
```

For comparison, single quotes ('), don't allow string interpolation and treat any `#{}` sections as any other character.